# Content Editable div problems with editing

Tags: html, wysiwyg, contenteditable

I have problems with editing content editable div (it is styled to look like a text area). I am right now showing this html inside the div.

```
<p>
     Hey [Recipient Name],
</p>
<p>
    I'm using <b>Planning Simple&trade;</b> to organize <b>Ranni Hill Mud Race</b>. Click on the RSVP button below to check out the details and get involved.
</p>

<p>
    Hope to see you there! <br>prince
</p>
```

You can see the page here `http://96.126.109.96:850/test_invitation`. Here the invitation content is displayed in a content editable div. If I try to replace a whole paragraph, the whole content is distorted.

Is there a way to fix this? Or is there a customizable WYSIWYG editor which can edit HTML and can be applied this kind of style?

Comment: Could you give a bit more detail on what you're trying to do? Specifically the "replace a whole paragraph" bit.

Comment: @TimDown..for example, if I try to select  `I am using Planning Simple™ to organize Ranni Hill Mud Race. Click on the RSVP button below to check out the details and get involved. ` (Infact I am not able to select it fully) and hit backspace inorder to clear that part, it gets distorted. and then another issue is I am not able to hit enter in between to create a new line, it gets distorted. (These are in FireFox latest version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the `float:left` from the

> .inner-cont-blk p

rule it works much better.

Comment: Thank you very much @alfonsoML..I was thinking that this behavior had to do with the contenteditable div. You saved me here.